# Google play Store App Review Guidelines Checklist

Tags: google-play, android

is there any guidance for Google play Store App Review Guidelines Checklist before submit into app store.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you publish your apps on Google Play and distribute them to users, you need to get the apps ready, test them, and prepare your promotional materials. Here is **Google's official checklist** to get your app ready for **successful launch on Google Play**:

1. Understand the Publishing Process
2. Understand Google Play Policies and Agreements
3. Test for Quality
4. Determine your App’s Content Rating
5. Determine Country Distribution
6. Confirm the App's Overall Size
7. Confirm the App's Platform and Screen Compatibility Ranges
8. Decide Whether your App will be Free or Priced
9. Consider using In-app Billing
10. Set Prices for your Products
11. Start Localization
12. Prepare Promotional Graphics, Screenshots, and Videos
13. Build and Upload the Release-ready APK
14. Plan a Beta Release
15. Complete the Apps’ Store Listing
16. Use Google Play Badges and Links in your Promotional Campaigns
17. Final Checks and Publishing
18. Support Users after Launch

Reference: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html